# How to disable/enable a range control in HTML using script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am quite new to html/jquery/javascript. I have below script on a button click which disables the range control. I need to re-enable the range control if the button is clicked second time. So how can I check whether the range control is disabled or enabled?

```
$(":button.range").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='range']:visible:first").attr("disabled","disabed");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$(":button.range").click(function(){
   let status = $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='range']:visible:first").prop('disabled');
   if(status === true){
      $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='range']:visible:first").prop('disabled',false);
   }else{
      $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='range']:visible:first").prop('disabled',true);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following jquery to know if input range control is disabled.

```
 if ($(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='range']").prop("disabled") === true) {
    //write your code for disabled range control
}
```

If you want to enable the same control, use jquery like below.

```
$(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='range']").prop("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just wish to toggle it you can use the script below:

```
$(":button.range").click(function(){
   let status = $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='range']:visible:first").prop('disabled');

   $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='range']:visible:first").prop('disabled', !status);
});
```

If it is `true` then it will set it to `false` vice versa.

Comment: Thank you!! This script giving me expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggleAttribute()` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute

My Example uses Vanilla JavaScript but i think you can use it also with your jQuery Example.

```js
$(":button.range").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='range']:visible:first").toggleAttribute("disabled");
});
```

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle')[0];
const rangeSlider = document.getElementById('start');

const toggleRange = () => {
  const status = rangeSlider.toggleAttribute('disabled');
  console.log(status);
};

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', toggleRange);
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="range" id="start" name="volume" min="0" max="11">
  <label for="volume">Volume</label>
</div>
<button class="toggle">toggle</button>
```